# OpenFB AngularJS getting the FBToken from local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework, ng-storage

So, I have an Ionic app that requires a FB login, all is good but what I need to do is add 2 custom headers to every API request. Again, this should work... The issue I am having is that for some reason I am unable to grab the 'fbtoken' that is set on successful login. Here is some code:

**LoginController:**

```
OpenFB.login('email, user_friends').then(
            function () {
                OpenFB.get('/me').success(function (user) {
                    $localStorage.fbuser = user; //Set the user in local storage.
                });

                RequestService.get($scope.baseUrl + 'user')
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        alert('Success!!!! ' + data);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        if(status = 401) alert('Not Authorized!');
                    });
            },
            function (error) {
                alert('OpenFB login failed' + error);
            });
    };
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $localStorage) {
            console.log($localStorage);
            return {
                'request': function(config) {

                    config.headers['Auth-Token'] = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("fbtoken"));
                    config.headers['Auth-Provider'] = 'facebook';
                    return config;
                }
            };
        });
});
```

I can access the fbuser from local storage that is being set in the controller. The only difference between fbuser & fbtoken if I take a look in Chrome Inspector is that the names are different:

```
fbtoken
ngStorage-fbuser
```

Is this the issue? can I get the value of fbtoken in to my inceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so rather than using ngStorage module, I decided to go native JS and ran `localStorage.setItem(option, value)` & `localStorage.getItem(option)`